# How to Clone Object Using DozerMapper in Camel Framework

Tags: apache-camel, dozer, spring-el

I have an object called realorder and I would like to clone that object Using .

```
<to uri="bean:DozerBeanMapper?method=map(Order.class,${header.realOrder.order})" />
<setHeader headerName="realOrder.CloneOrder">
  <spel>#{new org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper().map(com.gap.gid.oms.v1.complete.domain.order.Order.class,request.headers['realOrder.order'])}</spel>
</setHeader>
```

When I tried this, I am getting below Exception.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: 
    Line 42 in XML document from class path resource [com/services/routeContext-realOrder.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; 
    lineNumber: 42; columnNumber: 19; cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'setHeader' 
    cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
```

Comment: are you sure the xml you posted is the xml you tried to execute? this error means you have text/characters under the `<setHeader>` element, which is not the case in your sample.